# Best practice to COPY QUERY RESULTS from MULTIPLE JOINED TABLES of ONE DATABASE to another DATABASE?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

- I have several joined tables with much data inside of one postgreSQL (version 9.6.4) database called 'sourceDB'.
- I need to query all these tables and copy the results from 'sourceDB' to a second (empty) postgreSQL (also version 9.6.4) database called 'destinationDB', which doesn't have a database scheme, but should have the same database scheme like 'sourceDB'.
- Both databases are on the same host system and have to be controlled via a JAVA application.

**What I've tried so far is this:**

1. Determine the database scheme of 'sourceDB'.
2. Run the "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ..." statement for all existing tables of 'sourceDB' on 'destinationDB' to ensure that both databases have the same database scheme. This works pretty well!
3. Run the DB query (SELECT DISTINCT ...) for each table (on 'sourceDB') to get the data and after that run for each table the 'copyTableData' function to copy the results (via INSERT INTO) to 'destinationDB':

**JAVA-Code:**

```
  String[] tables = new String[]{
                    "table1",
                    "table2_table4",
                    "table3_addresses",
                    "table4",
                    "table5",
                    "table6",
                    "table7",
                    "table8",
                    "table9",
                    "table10",
                    "table11",
                    "table12"
  };

  int counter = 0;

  for( String table : tables ){
        int copyProcess = 100/tables.length*counter;

        if (counter == 0){
              System.out.println(importApp.getDateTime() + 
                    "Initiating Import - Importing table '" + table + "'");
        } else {
              System.out.println(importApp.getDateTime() + 
                    copyProcess + " % completed - Importing table '" + table + "'");
        }

        getDataFromSrcDB = "SELECT DISTINCT " + table + ".* " +
              "FROM table1 " +
                    "FULL JOIN table2_table4 " +
                      "ON table2_table4.d_id=table1.d_id " +
                    "FULL JOIN table3_addresses " +
                      "ON table3_addresses.d_id=table2_table4.d_id " +
                    "FULL JOIN table4 " +
                      "ON table4.p_id=table2_table4.p_id " +
                    "FULL JOIN table5 " +
                      "ON table5.d_id=table1.d_id " +
                    "FULL JOIN table6 " +
                      "ON table6.d_id=table1.d_id " +
                    "FULL JOIN table7 " +
                      "ON table7.d_id=table1.d_id " +
                    "FULL JOIN table8 " +
                      "ON table8.d_id=table1.d_id " +
                    "FULL JOIN table9 " +
                      "ON table9.d_id=table1.d_id " +
                    "FULL JOIN table10 " +
                      "ON table10.id=table6.id " +
                    "FULL JOIN table11 " +
                      "ON table11.d_id=table1.d_id " +
                    "FULL JOIN table12 " +
                      "ON table12.a_id=table3_addresses.a_id " +
                    "WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_MakeEnvelope(" +
                      myApp.minLong + "," +
                      myApp.minLat + "," +
                      myApp.maxLong + "," +
                      myApp.maxLat + ",4326), geom :: GEOMETRY) OR " +
                    "ST_Intersects(ST_MakeEnvelope(" +
                      myApp.minLong + "," +
                      myApp.minLat + "," +
                      myApp.maxLong + "," +
                      myApp.maxLat + ",4326), CAST(table5.location AS GEOMETRY))";

                      myApp.copyTableData(dbConnOnSrcDB, dbConnOnDestDB, getDataFromSrcDB, table);
                      counter++;
            }
```

4. Now copy the query results to 'destinationDB' (via INSERT INTO):

**JAVA-Code:**

```
  public void copyTableData(Connection dbConnOnSrcDB, Connection dbConnOnDestDB, String sqlQueryOnSrcDB, String tableNameOnDestDB) throws SQLException {

    try (

        PreparedStatement prepSqlStatmOnSrcDB = dbConnOnSrcDB.prepareStatement(sqlQueryOnSrcDB);

        ResultSet sqlResultsFromSrcDB = prepSqlStatmOnSrcDB.executeQuery()

    ) {
        ResultSetMetaData sqlMetaResults = sqlResultsFromSrcDB.getMetaData();

        // Stores the query results
        List<String> columnsOfQuery = new ArrayList<>();

        // Store query results
        for (int i = 1; i <= sqlMetaResults.getColumnCount(); i++)
            columnsOfQuery.add(sqlMetaResults.getColumnName(i));

        try (
            PreparedStatement prepSqlStatmOnDestDB = dbConnOnDestDB.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO " + tableNameOnDestDB +
                     " (" + columnsOfQuery.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) + ") " +
                        "VALUES (" + columnsOfQuery.stream().map(c -> "?").collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) + ")")
        ) {

            final int batchSize = 1000;
            int count = 0;
            while (sqlResultsFromSrcDB.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= sqlMetaResults.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    prepSqlStatmOnDestDB.setObject(i, sqlResultsFromSrcDB.getObject(i));
                }

                prepSqlStatmOnDestDB.addBatch();
                if (++count % batchSize == 0) {
                    prepSqlStatmOnDestDB.executeBatch();
                }
            }

            // Insert remaining records
            prepSqlStatmOnDestDB.executeBatch();

            prepSqlStatmOnDestDB.close();
            prepSqlStatmOnSrcDB.close();
        }
    }
  }
```

My problem is that I am not that experienced in (Postgres) SQL, so I am not sure if my approach is good (efficient / effective) respectively what's in fact the common best practice to achieve that?

Another problem is that the first copyTableData function call (in terms of 'table1') works pretty well, but if the copyTableData function is called for the second time (for 'table2' or 'table3', or ...) I get an JAVA exception that there is a row that already contains the values (null, null, null, null, null, null). I am not sure how to interpret that...:

- Do you think the problem at the second INSERT INTO is that INSERT INTO has problems with already existing primary keys like d_id, because of the first copyTableData function call (in terms of 'table1')?
- Or does INSERT INTO really has problems with Null-values?

Comment: I would create a `materialized view` in the target database that joins all the tables from the source database using a dblink or a foreign data wrapper - much simpler setup and most probably a lot faster too.

Comment: Postges has means implemented to access, what they call ["Foreign Data"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-foreign-data.html). Amongst others, this can be used to access data from another Postgres server from within the database itself. The tabley of the remote database can then be queried as if they were local. Have you opted to use your Java program instead because you didn't know about that or is there a specific reason why you didn't chose the direct approach via foreign data wrappers?

Comment: Well I didn't know anything about the existence of foreign data wrappers. Could you please explain me what's the advantage of that and why should I use that?

Comment: You wouldn't have to write a Java program for making your copies, a simple `INSERT INTO foreign_schema.elbat (...) SELECT ... FROM local_schema.elbat WHERE ...` would be enough (Exchange `foreign_schema` and `local_schema` if you're on the foreign database. And of course the `SELECT` can be more complex e.g. including joins.). That would also reduce the overhead a Java program might produce.